# Mactex svg package error: graphaside_svg-tex.pdf is missing

Tags: pdftex, mactex, svg

I have a .svg graphic in a tex document. I am getting the following error when I use mactex:

> Package svg Warning: You didn't enable `shell escape' (or`write18')
>   (svg)                so it wasn't possible to launch the Inkscape
>   export (svg)                for `figures/graphaside.svg' on input line
>   149.
>
> ! Package svg Error: File `graphaside_svg-tex.pdf' is missing.

Using Sharelatex the file compiles fine, on my Mac it does not.

What's going on?

Comment: You need to enable shell escape when you compile. Are you using a front end to compile or compiling directly in Terminal?

Comment: I'm using pdftex via terminal

Comment: Use `pdftex —shell-escape`.

Answer (score 0):

As warning goes, try combine program with argument `-shell-escape`. Also make sure Inkscape is installed.